# Determine if sum is a power of 2

Tags: algorithm, math

What is the fastest (in asymptotic worst-case time complexity) algorithm for determining if a sum of arbitrary positive integers is a power of two?

Comment: What operations are you allowed to use?

Comment: @RenéG That doesn't really answer the question. For instance, is addition considered to be constant-time, regardless of the size of the operands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One cute bit twiddling trick is to test if `x&(x-1)` is equal to 0.

Note that you need to decide what to do if x is equal to 0, this test will mark 0 as a power of 2 so you may want an exception for this case.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract 1 from the sum and perform a bitwise AND with the original number. Powers of 2 will have a result of 0.